# Floating Label background to be removed while INPUT element is on focus

Tags: html, css, user-interface, sass, floating-labels

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvT4S.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvT4S.png)

I am unable to make the floating label's background same as the body bg while focusing on the text field of the form. The label overlaps with the border of the text field. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

I am expecting something like this..

[image]

Comment: Share your HTML and CSS code

Comment: I have sent you my HTML & CSS code... Thanks..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="p-fluid mb-2">
                  <span class="p-float-label"
                    [ngClass]="personalForm.get('basicInformation.middleName')?.hasError('required') && personalForm.get('basicInformation.middleName')?.invalid?'border-red':''">
                    <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="middleName" (change)="OnChange($event)"
                      (keypress)="keyPressAlphanumeric($event);keyPressFirstSpaceRestrict($event)" placeholder="&nbsp;">
                    <label>
                      {{'common.Middlename' | translate}}
                    </label>
                  </span>
                </div>

.p-float-label input:focus~label,
.p-float-label input.p-filled~label,
.p-float-label textarea:focus~label,
.p-float-label textarea.p-filled~label,
.p-float-label .p-inputwrapper-focus~label,
.p-float-label .p-inputwrapper-filled~label {
  top: -3px;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #999;
}
```